# Why can't SQL Server database name begin with a number if I run a query?

Tags: sql-server, database

Recently I found an anomaly with SQL Server database creation. If I create with the sql query

```
create database 6033SomeDatabase;
```

It throws an error.

But with the Management Studio UI, I can manually create a database with a name of `6033SomeDatabase`.

Is this expected behaviour or is it a bug? Please throw some light on this issue.

Comment: Try use square brackets in your code: `CREATE DATABASE [123]`. It should help.

Comment: See [database identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) for more details (as with just about any language, there are rules about identifiers)

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Thanks. It helped. But If i run this query:
create database something;
It works. So, why this exception for a database name beginning with number.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I changed the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
IF DB_ID('6033SomeDatabase') IS NULL
  CREATE DATABASE [6033SomeDatabase]
```

Comment: while this code block might answer the question, please try to improve your answer with relevant explanation http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you detailed answer.

SQL syntax imposes some restrictions to names of database, tables, and fields. F.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM SELECT, FROM WHERE SELECT.Id = FROM.SelectId
```

SQL parser wouldn't parse this query. You should rewrite it:

```
SELECT * FROM [SELECT], [FROM] WHERE [SELECT].Id = [FROM].SelectId
```

Another example:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Code = 123e10
```

Is `123e10` the name of column in `T1`, or is it a numeric constant for 123×10<sup>10</sup>? Parser doesn't know.

Therefore, there are rules for naming. If you need some strange database or table name, you can use brackets to enclose it.